# Is encrypting all columns in a mysql table a good practice for security?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, security, encryption

I am building a laravel application and using MySQL as the database. The client is extremely concerned about the user-specific data and wants to encrypt all data in certain tables so that even if the database is compromised the user's data is not easily exposed. Example of user-specific data is his name, mobile, email and columns similar to this

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a good practice if the client wants it.

Comment: @BillKarwin How can I convince the client not to do this.

Comment: You could, yes if the data is really _that_ sensitive, and/or there's some legislation/regulation about it in the client's location/industry, and/or the deployed environment is very vulnerable for some reason. Beware of an impact on performance though (due to the overhead of decrypting and encrypting all day long). Usually other protections to secure the wider environment and keep the database out of sight are sufficient. Mostly it's just passwords which are hashed (rather than encrypted).

Comment: Stack Overflow is for code problems. The question of convincing the client of something is not a code problem. Good luck, I sympathize but I have no solution for you.